# selenium AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to make a program that works like [this](https://replit.com/@AndrewKimmel/Virtual-Browser) but i keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python/VirtualBrowser/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=r'VirtualBrowser/chromedriver')
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.service.start()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start'
```

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.binary_location = "/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python/VirtualBrowser/chromedriver" 
chromeDriver = 'VirtualBrowser/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromeDriver)
driver.get("https://google.com")
input("Running...")
```

im not exactly the greatest at debugging and most of the code is fixes that ive tried and they have worked towards throwing less errors. any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I don't think chromeDriver should be a string, because when you pass it as the service parameter to webdriver.Chrome, it tries to call `service.start()`, which it can't. Maybe take a look at [this](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.html) page

Comment: use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/77815918/12780274`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromeDriver)` where service kwarg should be a service object.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# ...
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_service = Service("path")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=chrome_service)
```

Comment: that fixed the original error, but now I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'` and my code looks like this now `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_service = Service("/workspaces/codespaces-blank/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=chrome_service)
driver.get("https://google.com")
input("Running...")`

Comment: @szal It seems that the `Service` class is not created correctly. Check the path to the `chromedriver`, e.g. should there be a slash at the beginning? Did you mean to write `~/workspaces/codespaces-blank/chromedriver` instead? Or just type `chromedriver` and open a terminal in the `chromdriver` directory. Actually, you shouldn't need to specify the path to `chromedriver` (just specify options if necessary) `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`.

Comment: i dont think that the path is an issue because whenever I add the ~ or change the path in any way it throws `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`

Comment: @szal Works the other solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why don't work, but if you remove `service` probably it works if you have the driver in the same folder that your code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

instead of

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromeDriver)
```

Anyway I use this code:

```
import requests
import zipfile
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_version = '100.0.4896.60'
chrome_driver_file = 'chromedriver'
chrome_driver_file_zip = 'chromedriver_linux64.zip'
url_chrome_driver = f'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/{chrome_driver_version}/{chrome_driver_file_zip}'

file = requests.get(url_chrome_driver, allow_redirects=True)
open(chrome_driver_file_zip, 'wb').write(file.content)

with zipfile.ZipFile(chrome_driver_file_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('.')
    chrome_driver_file = zip_ref.namelist()[0]
    
os.remove(chrome_driver_file_zip)
os.chmod(chrome_driver_file, 0o775)


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

and works