# Unable to use Selenium Webdriver. Getting two exceptions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exception, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following error when trying to create an object with Selenium Webdriver.

```
"\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 42, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path

"\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 74, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
"\selenium_webdriver_webscraping.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
"\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, self.options)
"\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 44, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to obtain {service.path} using Selenium Manager; {err}")
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager; 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

This is the code I used:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = <chrome drive .exe path>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If the Selenium version you are using is v4.6.0 or above (which I think it is as I see `SeleniumManger` in the error trace), then you don't really have to set the `driver.exe` path. Selenium can handle the browser and drivers by itself.

So your code can be simplified as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

A few references:

- *[Purpose of webdriver manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453996/purpose-of-webdriver-manager/76455537#76455537)*
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Comment: Simple and efective! Just updated the selenium version and don't need to have webdriver anymore

Comment: Awesome Solution. hopefully the new selenium is less unnecessary commands. Great !

Comment: I'm running selenium `4.15.2` and still get the `NoSuchDriverException` error when using this method

Comment: Some guys tell install 4.6 version while Pypi has 4.16 as the latest version of selenium.

Answer (score 9):

This is due to changes in Selenium 4.10.0:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, and that `desired_capabilities` has been removed, but there is now another way of passing it in. See *[Upgrade to Selenium 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#capabilities)* for the documentation on how to pass in desired capabilities when using Selenium 4.10.0 (or newer).

Also, if you want to set an `executable_path`, it can be passed in via the `service`, but it is no longer necessary, as selenium manager is included.

Here's a code snippet with everything you need:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I'm running `4.15.2` and still get the `NoSuchDriverException` error when using this method

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Because I set the path of `chromedriver.exe` to `webdriver.Chrome()` as shown below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
```

So, I removed the path from `webdriver.Chrome()` as shown below, then the error was solved. *This is recommended and you can see the answers of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915334/which-version-of-chrome-driver-does-webdriver-chrome-get-in-selenium-with-py) about which version of chrome driver `webdriver.Chrome()` gets:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Or, I set the path to [Service()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=chrome%20service#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.service) and set it to `webdriver.Chrome()` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

And, I got the same error below because I did not download and set [chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) in `django-project`:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to locate or obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

This is my code:

```py
# "tests/test_1.py"

from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

class TestBrowser1(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
        driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in driver.title
```

So, I downloaded `chromedriver.exe` and set it to the root directory in `django-project` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 |-tests
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  └-test_1.py
 └-chromedriver.exe # Here
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of Selenium which you are using is v4.6 or above.
I run a correct code run my laptop, But when I run same code on another laptop, that have the error. I realized that it was installed selenium v4.16 . I install 3.141.0 version selenium and that work perfectly.

```
pip install selenium==3.141.0

Installing collected packages: selenium
  Attempting uninstall: selenium
    Found existing installation: selenium 4.16.0
    Uninstalling selenium-4.16.0:
      Successfully uninstalled selenium-4.16.0
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `time.sleep`

Full code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

website = "website"
path = r'path'
driver = webdriver.Chrome( )
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(100)
driver.quit()
```

This worked for me, and you can add as much time as you need