# WebDriver Manager java.lang.NoSuchMethodError1

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdrivermanager-java

I use Java+selenium+testng+maven. And I tried to use WebDriver Manager instead of standard usage. After declaration according to the instruction of API, I ran into a problem. When compiling the errors occur:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/File;)V

at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader.download(Downloader.java:128)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager.manage(BrowserManager.java:277)
```

Comment: <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>

<dependency>
          <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
          <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.0</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: have you tried to rebuild maven or try to use lower version, like

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: You need to provide more code to allow people to help you. Not just the error.

Comment: Refer this if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719443/7598774

Comment: public void setup(String br)
  {
   logger = Logger.getLogger("CCMTAutomation");
   PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

  
   try {
    if (br.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
     setupChrome();
    } else {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid browser parameter: " + br);
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle and report the exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    Assert.fail("Error setting up WebDriver: " + e.getMessage());
   }
  }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.