# io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Error HTTP 403 executing https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/?restype=container&comp=list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver, webdrivermanager-java

I am running my Selenium automation code in Edge via Jenkins and getting the below error :

```
Caused by: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: Error HTTP 403 executing https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/?restype=container&comp=list
```

It is running fine on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Refer this if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response code 403 indicates that you may have hit the traffic rate limit of GitHub.

To avoid this problem, WebDriverManager can make authenticated requests using a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). See the [advanced configuration](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/doc/asciidoc/index.adoc#advanced-configuration) section to discover how to set up this token in WebDriverManager.

Additionally, if you are using WebDriverManager 5.3.0, this issue should not happen anymore (even without a GitHub token).

For more information, you can refer to [this doc](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/doc/asciidoc/index.adoc#http-response-code-403).

Comment: I tried using WebDriverManager 5.3.0. I even tried with 5.4.0 version but does not seem to work.

Comment: @ValiTu Sounds like the doc needs an update. You can also report this issue on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues).