# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities' in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

[Code screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42Rw.png) [Code screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz0Ih.png)

Getting error when using selenium in colab

I am trying to use selenium in colab but they show attribute error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py in get_path(service, options)
     38             path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
     39         except Exception as err:
---> 40             msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
     41             raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
     42 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

Comment: Check this answer  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use Selenium Webdriver. Getting two exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461596/unable-to-use-selenium-webdriver-getting-two-exceptions)

Answer (score 13):

For the current version of selenium, you can't pass executable_path to Chrome() directly. If you want to reference a specific downloaded version of ChromeDriver try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

cService = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='/Users/[...]binaries(117)/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = cService)
```

For windows reference the .exe itself.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python), I had a similar problem and it guided me.
Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

urls = [

    'https://www.techwithtim.net/' 
        
        ]
s = Service(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The version of Selenium which you are using is v4.6 or above. I have same Error and I solved.
Just installed older version:

```
pip install selenium==3.141.0

Installing collected packages: selenium   Attempting uninstall: selenium
    Found existing installation: selenium 4.16.0
    Uninstalling selenium-4.16.0:
      Successfully uninstalled selenium-4.16.0 Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0
```