# Selenium: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute the following simple code in python 3.11.4 and selenium 4.14:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

But I'm getting the following error, Is there any solution?

```
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path      
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 98, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 144, in run       
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json.
{'code': 65, 'message': 'Unsuccessful response (403 Forbidden) for URL https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MENG\Desktop\SAFProject\Project.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__        
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path      
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I have tried updating pip, python, and selenium, and installing selenium in a separate environment, but still the problem exists.

---

When I tried this version of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/MENG/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
```

The error is like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path      
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 79, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MENG\Desktop\SAFProject\Project.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/MENG/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__        
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MENG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path      
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928765/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-capabilities-in-selenium/77309919#77309919

Comment: Awesome, it worked, thanks