# Chrome browser opens and closes immediately after it runs - Selenium web driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am just invoking a chrome browser by entering a URL of the page. It opens a browser and closes immediately. However, I have added the dependencies on the POM.xml file.

You can find the code below,

```java
    package com.Rezaid.webdriver;
    
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    
    public class OpenBrowser {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//BiTS//Downloads//chromedrivers//chromedriver.exe");
            
              ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                
                driver.get("https://www.google.com");
                
                System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
```

I want you to tell me the solution so that I can run the code.

The errors are shown below,

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 10550
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and share the error stack trace from the console?

Comment: I have added the comments. Please check @Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which version of selenium you are using, since the chrome version in your system is `116`, you need to upgrade your selenium to latest one which is `4.11.0`. Check below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And once you have upgraded, setting `System.setProperty` path is no longer mandatory, you can skip that line. Selenium will internally download and manage the drivers for you. Code can be simplified as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
}
```

Refer these answers for questions with similar issues:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76929533/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();` to initiate the Chrome browser and use below in your pom file

```
<dependencies>
<!-- Other dependencies -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update the selenium version to 4.11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).