# Selenium can't find webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm getting this error when I try to run Selenium:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

I tried to put webdriver in many different locations on my desktop but it is not working:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe
```

or

```
./chromedriver.exe
```

Any idea? I've installed latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
```

Above line of code in incorrect. You have to pass the absolute path(full location path) of the `chromedriver.exe`. Else, if you are using latest version of selenium, check the solution below.

Assuming you are using latest version of selenium (`v4.11.2`), code can be simplified as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

Refer this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774