# Failed to open a website by using python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook
My chrome version = 116.0.5845.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)
my downloaded chromedrive = https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

and i saved the chromedrive .exe in C:\Program File (x86), but when I tired the below codes, the codes are not working

```
!pipe install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program File (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Error = 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

```
!pipe install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Create a WebDriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")

# Open a website
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Error = 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

What can I do?

I expected that my targeted website will be opened by the chromedrive

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are using selenium `v4.6.0` or above, your code can be as simple as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

No need to worry about downloading and setting the `chromedriver.exe` path. Refer below link for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

- For some specific reason if you want to set the `chromedriver.exe` path, then starting selenium `v4.10.0` this is how you need to set it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service(executable_path='<full path/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

You need to pass the driver via [Service Class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=chrome%20service#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.service) as shown above.