# Trying to test using Python Selenium - Error seen in the console

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, pycharm, automated-tests

I'm beginner, so I don't understand the reason this type of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kerem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kerem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kerem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kerem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\download_manager.py", line 29, in download_file
    response = self._http_client.get(url)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kerem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 36, in get
    self.validate_response(resp)
  File "C:\Users\kerem\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 19, in validate_response
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: response body:
Google-Edge-Cache: forbidden
Error: 7
request url:
https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip
response headers:
{'content-length': '37', 'content-type': 'text/plain', 'x-request-id': 'ca594d4d-aa62-4ebf-8c4c-04a30cc6a844', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000', 'date': 'Tue, 05 Sep 2023 16:00:53 GMT', 'server': 'Google-Edge-Cache'}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was trying to Run this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: selenium 4.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to using Selenium, I assume you downloaded a recent version of Selenium. Nonetheless, you are using an obsolete piece of code to start a web driver.

This code would be something like that in the new versions of Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Read more at Selenium Documentation: [Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You are using latest version of selenium, you don't really need to use third party libraries such as `ChromeDriverManager` to manage your browser drivers. Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774