# chromedriver not found, while using selenium webdriver on VSCode codespace

Tags: visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

Im using VSCode connected to my repository, uding .ipynb(Jupyter Notebook) for practicing basic web scraping
I use selenium, so i installed both selenium and webdriver-manager

```
!pip install selenium==4.1.0
!pip install webdriver-manager==3.5.2

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium import webdriver
import time

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
options.binary_location = "(driver) chromedriver.exe"
```

But as I load the webdriver, it makes '*Output is truncated*' error

I googled some, and I tried this method : making another *WebDriverException*

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='(driver) chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
```

tho chromedriver.exe is in the location
[chromdriver in same directory with .ipynb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOUaz.png)

Comment: You no longer need to use driver managers. [As of Selenium 4.6](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/), Selenium contains it's own driver manager. My suggestion is to remove the external driver manager, update Selenium to the newest version, and try again. It should just work.

Comment: you mean i can install only selenuim, and import webdriver from it, and simply webdriver.Chrome()?

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: @screamingpeanut Yes, that's all you need.

Comment: @tysm! i was little busy to check this page, but it helped me anyway