# Selenium not able to launch application with driver.get() . selenium==4.13.0 and chrome== 118.0.5993.70

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('executables/chrome-win64/chrome.exe')

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)
print("Hello.....")
# Launch the application
driver.get("https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads")

driver.close()
```

Program is getting hanged at step

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, //options=chromeOptions)
```

and application is not getting launched.

Comment: the service is the chromedriver... so you'd set that to the path to the chromedriver executable, not the browser.  I think you'd need "options.binary_location" for Chrome browser if it's not in PATH.

Comment: Chrome is getting launched properly but after that it throws below exception: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service executables/chrome-win32/chrome.exe

Comment: yeah, it's launching the browser, thinking it's launching chromedriver.  You want to launch chromedriver which will then launch the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** You need to pass the location of browser driver which is `chromedriver.exe` in the [Service](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/) argument. And not the location of browser binary(`chrome.exe`).

**Solution:** Change the line of code as below:

```
s = Service('<full path>/chromedriver.exe')
```

**Suggestion:**
Having said the above, since you are using latest selenium version, you do not have to worry about manually setting the chrome driver location. Selenium will download and manage the driver automatically for you. Your code can be simplified as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
print("Hello.....")
# Launch the application
driver.get("https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads")
driver.close()
```

Refer this answer for more details about browser driver management by Selenium:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774