# What is the solution of this python selenium error?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("http://youtube.com")
```

I have chrome version 118.0.5993.118, but I downloaded chromedriver version 118.0.5993.70. It was because there was no chromedriver version 118.0.5993.118.
Then I have problem running code above, even though it is gramatically correct.

Is it because of the wrong chromedriver version?
Then what will be the solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line is incorrect.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
```

**Solution:** From selenium `v4.10.0` and onwards, you cannot pass `executable_path`(chrome driver path) as an argument. You need to use [Service Class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=chrome%20service#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.service) to pass the `chromedriver.exe` path.

**Option 1:** Passing `chromedriver.exe` path using `Service` class.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='<full path>/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
browser.get("http://youtube.com")
```

**Option 2:** This is the easiest option. If your selenium version is `4.6.0` or above, let Selenium's built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) do the driver management for you. No need to set the `chromedriver.exe` explicitly. Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://youtube.com")
```

Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774