# Python selenium chromedriver attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I don't know why my code suddenly doesn't work. chromedriver.exe is in the same directory, and this code worked perfectly fine before. After updating to the latest selenium it suddenly doesn't work. Python 3.9, selenium version 4.14.0, chromedriver version 118
[image: my code]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
```

Above is incorrect. In the latest selenium, you need to pass `chromedriver.exe` through [Service Class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=chrome%20service#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.service). See code below.

**Option1:** Passing `chromedriver.exe` path using `Service` class.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='<full path>/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("http://youtube.com")
```

**Option2:** This is the easiest option. Since you are using latest selenium. Latest selenium has an option to automatically manage `chromedriver.exe`. No need to manually download and set the path of `chromedriver.exe`. Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://youtube.com")
```

Few references to know more about option 2:

- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: About option 2. if I don't include the chromedriver.exe path won't selenium just use the chrome on my computer?

Comment: `chrome` and `chromedriver.exe` are 2 different things. `chrome` is your browser itself and `chromedriver` is the driver which selenium uses to launch the chrome browser on your computer. In option 2, selenium will download the `chromedriver.exe` programmatically from web and uses it to interact with the browser in your computer. Hope this helps. Refer the links in the answer for more info.