# How to match chromedriver and chrome brower version?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrUFg.png)
How to fix this error?
Help me.

I am trying web scraping by using selenium.

How to match chromedriver and chrome brower version?
How to fix this error?

```
profile_name = 'File Downloader'
profile_path = rf'{os.path.expanduser("~")}\Chrome Profiles\{profile_name}'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={profile_path}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={profile_name}')
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--download.default_directory=Download_contanier")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path="C:/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"), options=chrome_options)
browser.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of selenium do you use? If it's version `4.6.0` or higher, then let the [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) do the handling of `chromedriver.exe`. You do not have to explicitly set the path of the driver.

So change the below code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path="C:/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"), options=chrome_options)
```

**TO:**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=chrome_options)
```

Selenium Manager will check the chrome browser version in your system and accordingly download and use the matching `chromedriver.exe`.

Some useful references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)