# selenium has no attribute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities' in  "driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())"
```

I was try open google with selenium but I cant open I cant fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Service Class](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#:%7E:text=The%20Service%20classes%20are%20for,passed%20to%20the%20command%20line.) in the latest selenium versions to pass the driver executable path or `ChromeDriverManager` setup. See code below.

Change your code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

driver.quit()
```

**SUGGESTION:** If you are using latest selenium version, there is a more easy way to handle browser drivers. You don't need third party libraries like `ChromeDriverManager`. Selenium's built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) can do what `ChromeDriverManager` used to do.

Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 0):

Removing `ChromeDriverManager().install()` from the code will work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

driver.quit()
```

###### Note: Be sure to use `pip install -U selenium` to get the latest version as this works for selenium `<=4.10`