# Issues downloading chrome driver for Selenium 2023

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to download the latest version `119` of the chrome driver for Selenium. Can somebody guide me in this? how can I download it?

I followed the link https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ (provided by ChromeDriver website itself)

- and then pressed "STABLE" under Channel,
- then downloaded `chromedriver` for win32.
- After that I moved this file into a folder named "Selenium" under Desktop, and right click "Extract Here" within the Selenium folder
- then tried running the code on VS code `from selenium import webdriver`

but it seems like I still have issues importing the webdriver.

Comment: What selenium version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest selenium version (`v4.15.2`), you do not have to worry about all the steps you have mentioned in your question to download `chromedriver.exe`.

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will take care of all those things automatically. Code can be as simple as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
print(driver.title)
```

Console output:

```
Google

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: hey i have tried using this code on VScode, it should open a webpage but whenever it tries to open a webpage, it closes by itself within seconds ...what should i do

Comment: Any errors you see on the console, or do you see the page title getting printed?