# Git-Hub selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, github, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Visual Studio code on git hub and I keep getting the same error mentioned in the title this is the code I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import multiprocessing
import time
import csv


#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Imports
website = 'https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/'
path = r'/workspaces/web_Scrape/Stock project/Drivers/chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path), options=options)
driver.get(website)
```

this works fine on my home windows machine and the program runs as intended but I cant figure out what's causing the issue here. I have had a look at other people asking the same question but the solutions offered have not worked.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/workspaces/web_Scrape/Stock project/chromedriver.exe'
```

Comment: Why don't you let selenium handle `chromedriver.exe`. Refer this on how to do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with Github.

Comment: if that path is correct, seems like that's linux?  That linux driver would not have .exe extension.  If that's not the issue, then check permissions on the chromedriver.exe file for the user that runs the code.  You might also want an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone i have found the answer and fixed the code by using the following:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(website)
```

Thank you for all the help.