# Selenium not working with correct chromedriver version and chrome version

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to just write a hello world with selenium and have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/[...]/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 75, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\[...]\ets.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/[...]/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am using Chrome version: 119.0.6045.200
And ChromeDriver: 119.0.6045.105

I cant find anything on it, thanks for the help

Comment: I don't believe passing the chromedriver path as an argument to `Chrome()` is the correct way to do it.  Why are you doing it that way?  Are you following some tutorial?

Comment: It is always better to refer documentation for stuff like this, see this [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the driver by:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

then:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

You don't need `driver.exe` anymore

doc: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should work. You don't have to set the "driver.exe" because you have `SeleniumManager`.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using latest selenium version.

**Option 1:** (Easy option)Just change the code as below, [SeleniumManager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will take care of `chromedriver.exe` management:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

No need of setting the `chromedriver.exe` path manually. Refer below answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

**Option 2:** For any reason you want to explicitly pass `chromedriver.exe` then follow the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('C:/Users/[...]/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

try this,without the path of Chromedriver