# Selenium: selenium-manager.exe blocked

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I am setting up a new Selenium maven project in Eclipse and am using selenium version 4.18.1

In pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.18.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

My java version is 1.11

Whenever I try to run a simple test, I get the error:

```
*Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain: Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}, error Failed to run command: [--browser, chrome, --language-binding, java, --output, json]
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.22'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver*
```

I also get a popup indicating that selenium-manager.exe has been blocked by my organisation due to security implications. When investigating, i found the following ongoing bug associated with selenium-manager.exe: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13130

This indicates that it will continue to be blocked by security until a fix has been made.

I have to use these version of Selenium in order to be compatible with my Chrome version 122.

My question is, is there anyway I can setup bypassing the use of selenium-manager.exe? I also have webdriver manager in my POM file - is it possible to use this instead?

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>oi.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried to use earlier versions of selenium-java but this is then incompatible with my chrome/java versions. I can't use an earlier java version as my system has automatically upgraded chrome and chrome driver versions to 122. I do not want to downgrade my chrome/chrome driver versions. I have read through all the questions I could find that relate to this but have not found a solution.

I have tried moving the location of the selenium-manager.exe file to see if I could open it elsewhere but I cannot.

Edit:
This is the simple test I'm trying to run:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class testRun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get("https://www.google.com");
       driver.getTitle();
       WebElement authenticate = driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit"));
       authenticate.click();
       System.out.println("test has ended");
       driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not set up the `chromedriver.exe` path manually using `Service` class?

Comment: @Shawn Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Check this answer. Refer Option 2 in the answer. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578748/7598774

Comment: Hi, I am using java and not python - I have added my simple test run above

Comment: Refer the code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer code below to set up `chromedriver.exe` manually in java.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\<full path>\\chromedriver.exe");
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

[Link to download latest stable chrome driver](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)

Comment: Thanks Shawn, that worked perfectly! I gave feedback on your answer however I don't yet have enough reputation to upvote