# Selenium session not created

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to test the source code of selenium/tests.py from CS50 Web, and I run I receive the message below. It seems my chromedriver is more updated than it requires, what shall I do with it?

```
The chromedriver version (87.0.4280.88) detected in PATH at C:\\Users\\zhoua\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (118.0.5993.89); currently, chromedriver 118.0.5993.70 is recommended for chrome 118.\*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87

Current browser version is 118.0.5993.89 with binary path C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe..."
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MBxb.png)

If anybody can help me to solve the selenium chromedriver version problem?

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You are using the old `chromedriver` compared to the `chrome` installed in your system. Can you edit your question and share your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** The error message says, you are using `v87.0.4280.88` of ChromeDriver which is not compatible with the chrome browser which is installed in your system which is `v118.0.5993.89`

**Solution:** You need to download the ChromeDriver from internet which is compatible with the chrome browser in your system.

Download the version `118` `chromedriver.exe` from below link:

For win32 platform - https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip

For win 64 platform - https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

Once you have downloaded the `chromedriver`, replace the new driver(`v118`) in the below path:

```
C:\\Users\\zhoua\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe
```

And then try to run your code.

**Option 2:** With latest selenium, you no longer have to worry about downloading the ChromeDriver manually from internet. Selenium will do that for you. For more info about this solution, check the below answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Hi Thanks for our answer, I have downloaded, 118 chromedriver.exe. But how can I relace the new driver in the path you mention?

Comment: Manually navigate to this location `C://Users/zhoua/Webdriver/`  and copy-paste the new  `chromedriver.exe`

Comment: it shows me this window but I cannot type anything or do anything with it:                 
Starting ChromeDriver 118.0.5993.70 (e52f33f30b91b4ddfad649acddc39ab570473b86-refs/branch-heads/5993@{#1216}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are saying. Can you try to be clear what is the exact issue now?

Comment: sorry, I manually navigate to this location, and paste chromedriver.ext, then it shows the message I pasted above.

Comment: Above message is just INFO not an ERROR. Does that mean the original error message which you have shared in the question is not showing now in the console? When you run your code, does the chrome browser launch successfully? And do you see any error in the console?

Comment: ok I find out, the version 118 in fact doesn´t work, so I downloaded the latest version 200 to replace it and now it works! Thank you for your patience! :D