# Getting an error using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-python

When I use selenium in python to open a website in chrome it give me an **Attribute Error**
This is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

And it give me this error :
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'`

I am expecting to open the chrome in [google](https://google.com).
And I tried to uninstall the modules and reinstall the modules one more time and tried to download the driver manually put in the option attribute but didn't work.

Comment: What version of selenium have you installed? Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 0):

You should use `playwright` instead, as it is a much newer python library and has many advantages over `selenium`.

Installation: `pip install playwright`, followed by: `playwright install`, and webkit, firefox, and chromium will be downloaded. Don't worry, you can still use chrome and msedge. Snippet of code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="chrome") #launches chrome browser
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com')
    print(page.title())
    page.locator('path to element').fill('text')
    browser.close()
```

Since you're using chrome, you want to add the channel argument like I have, but keep the chromium part. (Just copy my code and it should work). I showed as an example just a few of the functions the `playwright` library has. Note that `playwright` launches in headless mode by default, so you'll need to add an argument if you want to be able to see the browser launching.

The reason I suggest you use `playwright` instead of `selenium` is that `playwright` *does not* require a webdriver, and it is a much newer and up to date python library, and it has many more applications and features. This will also solve your `AttributeError`.