# Edge displaying blank page and "data:," in search bar with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I try to use Selenium with python and searching something on google.com. Problem is that when I initialize the driver and start looking for the website, only "data:," appears in the edge search bar and google is not loeading. I am using Edge version 120.0.2210.175 and the Edge Driver version 120.0.2210.175.

Here is my simple code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(r'C:/Users/XXXXXX/Documents/msedgedriver/msedgedriver.exe'))
url = 'https://google.fr'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
```

I tried to use latest version of the edge driver, but without success. I cannot change edge version.

Comment: Why don't you let [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) do the browser driver management. Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try, I just have to figure out how to use use the manager with a proxy.