# How to use Selenium without constantly running into ChromeDriver version errors?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there currently a way to automatically install the correct version of ChromeDriver whenever I run my Selenium script?

Today I got an error about the ChromeDriver and Chrome version. I got super confused while trying to fix it, I was uninstalling and reinstalling things, changing environments, I wasted so much time. Ultimately the problem was solved by just downloading [the latest ChromeDriver version from here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) (which was the first thing I tried, but I swear the version numbers were the same the first time I checked).

In my searching, I came across mentions of the webdriver-manager package which seemed really helpful, but I had trouble installing it and I can't tell if I'm supposed to use it with the latest version of Selenium or not (i have 4.18.0). I run this code about once a month and I've had version issues before, so it would be really useful if there were an indirect way to access ChromeDriver without having to download it myself every time there's a new version.

This is the code I'm currently using, where `chromedriver_path_variable` points to the local installation of chromedriver on my computer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

#Set up webdriver to read page
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path_variable)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)
```

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install `pip install webdriver-manager` and you good to go!

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import time 
    
    # Set up WebDriver options
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless') 
    option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

    # Use webdriver_manager to automatically install the correct ChromeDriver
    driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
    # Set up the WebDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, options=options)
    
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/home")
    time.sleep(10) # Wait for 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `webdriver-manager` library for this task

First, `pip install webdriver-manager`

Webdriver manager in this case would automatically install the most recent chromedriver version. This example should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install(), option=option))
```