# Selenium in python doesn't open chrome url

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-forms

When the browser opens it just stays put and doesn't act. The `driver.get(url)` doesn't make a request, nothing happens in the browser.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
import time

chrome_executable_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

# path to the chrome profile to get the logged google acc
chrome_profile_dir = r"C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3"

# use the chrome profile
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={chrome_profile_dir}")

service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_executable_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# this doesn't work, but it's not related to the url/nothing after this
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/myformid/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1824=abc&entry.20988=def&entry.1589=123"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

submit_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Enviar']"))
submit_button.click()

# wait for form submission
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
```

I believe it's related to the chrome launcher. I have to use the full chrome instance because I need to share the google session to be able to send the google form using my google account.

What I'm attempting is to submit a prefilled google form. I don't know how to get my current session to make the post request to /formresponse so I figured I would directly use the instance that is already logged in.

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: I read the documentation and I know it was innecesary, yet when Selenium handles it automatically it searches for the chrome driver, but I need to use the chrome executable to mantain the google session when accessing the google form

Comment: Your code to load a custom profile (`Profile 3`) looks fine. Just fix the 3 issues mentioned in my answer and you should be able to launch `Profile 3` successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues in your code:

1. `executable_path` argument accepts the path for `chromedriver.exe` and not `chrome.exe`.

Below line is incorrect

```
chrome_executable_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

It should be something like:

```
chrome_executable_path = r"C:\full path\chromedriver.exe"
```

Having said the above, you can always use [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/), where you do not have to worry about setting the driver manually. Below answer should help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

2. Below line has syntax error

```
submit_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Enviar']"))
```

It should be:

```
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Enviar']")
```

3. Last one, below import statement is missing in your code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from the need to specify the path of ChromeDriver as the executable_path not Chrome's itselves.

Download ChromeDriver and provide the path of this file to executable_path.
In your code you should use the path of ChromeDriver instead of chrome_executable_path.

Additionally use `find_element` instead of `findElement`.
With these corrections your browser will open the desired URL and perform the operations

Comment: Hello Umut, if I use chromedriver, which I used before, my session is not saved and I'm not logged in my google account, so I can't access the google form. The reason why I tried the chrome executable was to be logged in, which works. Perhaps I should make another question asking on how to keep my session to the driver. (I also tried chrome profiles)