# Selenium Error Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x000002B530C948B0>, but it must be an int, float or None

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to build something simple with Selenium but cannot get it off the ground at all

I have the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os

os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0' #Disable SSL


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

When I run it I am getting the below error:
Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x000002B530C948B0>, but it must be an int, float or None.

My Crome Driver is in the same folder as the Script

```
Py Version 3.11.8
Urllib3 version: 2.31.0
Selenium Version: 4.18.1
```

I have tried a number of different routes like using the Excution Path of the ChromeDriver

Or `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))` which gives me  a `WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service' Error.`

and changing the versions as suggested in a few posts

I am a bit stuck to be honest any pointers would be very helpful

Also Tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os

os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0' #Disable SSL

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open Scrapingbee's website
driver.get("http://www.scrapingbee.com")
```

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: @Shawn Still the same Error - I have tried it already.  Been round the houses a bit.  Starting to think about using a different solution

Comment: I restarted my machine and it started to work

Answer (score 0):

I just had to restart my machine and it started working