# Python geckodriver set up is unsuccesful

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, mozilla, geckodriver

I have a problem with `geckodriver.exe`.

I am going to create a bot but I dont know how to set up mozilla driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver 

geckodriver_yolu = "./geckodriver.exe" 

tarayici = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver_yolu)

tarayici.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRyjI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest selenium version(`v4.6.0` or above), then code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

tarayici = webdriver.Firefox()
tarayici.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will take care of driver management, no need to worry about setting `geckodriver.exe` path manually.

Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

And for any reason, if you wish to set the driver path manually, then below the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="C:/<fullpath>/geckodriver.exe")

tarayici = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
tarayici.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```