# Unable to interact with selenium webdriver after initializing it with the new service method [Python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to initialize a chrome webdriver with a custom user profile using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile XY')
service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
```

So far so good. Up until this point the code is executed and a new Chrome window pops up with the correct user profile selected. However, everything that comes after the initialization of the webdriver isn't executed anymore. E.g. the following code won't be executed.

```
print("This is a debug msg")
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

So my question is, how do i properly interact with the driver after it has been initialized if i cannot use driver.doSomething() anymore?

Any help would be appreciated.

Additional info: using the newest chrome and selenium versions.

See the above code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
```

Above is incorrect. You need to supply full path of `chromedriver.exe` not `chrome.exe` in `executable_path`

**Alternate solution:** You don't need to set the `chromedriver.exe` manually anymore. If you are using latest selenium(`v4.6.0` or above), you can skip setting path in the `executable_path`. See code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default')
service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
print("This is a debug msg")
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Console result:

```
This is a debug msg

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Refer this answer for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Maybe, i've closed this issue a bit to quickly. It seems that no supplying a path for the Service()-Function results in the incorrect user profile being loaded. Same for when trying to supply an executable_path. Any ideas what could be the cause for this?

Comment: Addendum: Apparently you have to manually select the profile selenium uses once and disable the query asking which profile to use on selenium start up...