I need to install chrome web driver but I can't figure out how
I am coding a bot on a website called pythonanywhere.com to visit a website a specific number of times to get profile views and I need to install chrome web driver to visit the website but I can't figure out how. I have installed selenium through pip install selenium but I'm not sure what the command is to install chrome web driver?
so far my code (without the actual part of inputting the website) is as follows:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Initialize web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # You need to download chromedriver and specify its path here

I installed selenium through pip install selenium but when I couldn't figure out the command for chrome web driver so my code doesn't work. I think I need to put something between the brackets next to wedriver.Chrome().

literally first answer on Google points to this site when searching for chromedriver

yes but I went onto that website and didnt understand how to use it, so I was hoping someone could explain @EdoAkse

Check this answer, it should help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

frankly, I suprised that you have problem. There are many questions on Stackoverflow in which you can see how to use it - ie. python - Can't use chrome driver for Selenium - Stack Overflow and webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

BTW:  on Linux I keep drivers in folder ~/bin and I have path ~/bin in environment variable PATH and I don't have to set path in webdriver.Chrome() or webdriver.Firefox(). In folder ~/bin I keep many other scripts and programs and I can run them without knowing full path.

If you are using the latest Selenium, at least 4.6, you don't have to manually download drivers, set them up, etc. Selenium Manager now takes care of that for you. Your code should work as is.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Initialize web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

See the link above and the docs for more info.
