test chrome issue within chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
driver_path = r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Udemy\chromedriver.exe"  # Replace with your correct path

# Create a Service object for the ChromeDriver
service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)

# Initialize the Chrome driver using the service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

i want this line of code to work
i tried running the code and the output was
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 124     
Current browser version is 123.0.6312.124 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF622D3F922+3045234]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6229E3652]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6228A7564]

i think the issue is with my chrome.
iam using chrome version 123
and chrome driver is of version 124
how can i use the test chrome version 124 for the program to run

As the exception message states the issue is in the mismatch between your chrome and chrome driver.

First option is upgrade chrome browser to v124

If for any reason you do not want to upgrade your browser, then manually download chromedriver.exe for v123 from below path and use it in your code to set driver path.
Link to download chrome driver v123 for win64 platform
Link to download chrome driver v123 for win32 platform

Third and easiest option is, use Selenium Manager to download and manage chrome drivers automatically. Your code can be simplified to:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()



Note: Option 3 is applicable only if your selenium version is 4.6.0 or higher.
For more info on option 3, refer below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774


When Selenium's driver manager isn't working, you can use the https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase driver manager:
(pip install seleniumbase and run with python)
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()

It will get the driver that you need. It also allows mismatched driver/browser pairings.

You need to update your chrome browser. In your chrome, click more(upper right corner) > help > about google chrome > relaunch
