Selenium - TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Service without an implementation for abstract method 'command_line_args'
Firstly I want to point out that I'm new to python and web scraping and I was learning how to web scrape with selenium.
I precisely followed a tutorial on how to set it up and suddenly an error occured - I searched for fixes on the web but I couldn't find one.
Can anyone help?
here is a screenshot of the code:
https://i.sstatic.net/WXkIGRwX.png

Change this:
from selenium.webdriver.common.service import Service 

To:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

Suggestion: If you are using selenium v4.6.0 or higher, you don't need to manually set the driver path. Hence you don't need Service class.
Code can be as simple as:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
UPDATE: If you do not want your browser to close automatically after the code has executed, then you need to detach the browser from driver object. Check the code below.
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")


Yep, that worked, but for some reason now the page opens and immediatly closes itself again. Any gueses why?

Hope you don't have driver.quit() at the end of your code? If not, then you need to detach browser from driver. Check the updated answer.

Ok, after applying your update everything works flawlessly, thank you very much

You need this:
import selenium.webdriver import ChromeService

...because that is an implementation of the abstract Service class
