How to install Chrome in Python virtual environment
File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:40136
from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 126
Current browser version is 125.0.6422.142

undetected-chromedriver==3.5.2 only support Chrome 114, and undetected-chromedriver==3.5.5 only support Chrome 126, the current Chrome version(dev) provide download is 127, The current stable version of Chrome is 125, I do not want any dev version of Chrome or virtual machine installed on my Windows machine, What's the best option I can have?
undetected-chromedriver==3.5.3 and undetected-chromedriver==3.5.4 have bugs

From the error I understand, the chrome driver used in your code is v126, however the chrome browser installed in your machine is v125. You have 2 options, either download v125 chromedriver and use it in your code. Or let Selenium Manager download and handle the chromedriver automatically for you. Refer this answer to know about Selenium Manager and how to use it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

instead of using chromedriver in physical path, you may like to use selenium wdm which is used in selenium 4 onwards. Selenium WDM automatically pick up latest version of your chromedriver and need not to store at physical location and dowlaod latest version every time browser version upgrades. upgrade your selenium to 4.21.0.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.21.0


It's called Selenium Manager not Selenium WDM. 2. "automatically pick up latest version of your chromedriver" - this is incorrect, Selenium Manager discovers the version of browser installed in the machine and downloads the matching chrome driver, not the latest version of chrome driver.

