selenium webdriver error.error is occured in PATH
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = r"D:\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.barnesandnoble.com/")

Error:

I try to primarily test the selenium. But it got an error. My chrome version is: Version 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) and chromedriver version :126.0.6478.126.

What version of selenium do you have? Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Please don't make links to images.  You can embed them in your post. Also it would be better to include the text of the error in your post rather than just an image.  It makes searching for problems/solutions better.

You can set the chrome driver path as given below.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')


Selenium 4 onwards, executable_path is deprecated. This code may work but with warnings. If the version is selenium 4 or above, Service object should be used to pass executable path. Reference
