WebDriver Error when using Selenium error: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
I'm using the code from the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#use-with-chrome.
After install and upgrade all package and running code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

I got an error:
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
I don't know how to resolve it since the last time I ran the driver it was working correctly without issue.
I appreciate your help guys.

Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774. You don't need WebDriverManager anymore.

Based on the Shaw comment and answer here: Unable to use Selenium Webdriver. Getting two exceptions
To open Chrom just used:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()


Removing the arg service from driver = webdriver.Chrome() worked for me.
from selenium import webdriver

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()


I installed the latest version and then used this command. worked like a charm. thank you.

solved the problem for me as well

Updating to 4.0.2 alone did not fix it for me. It was still trying to execute the "THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver" file instead of chromedriver.exe. After tracing through the code I found the .json file was replete, as were the driver directories, with old drivers. The simple fix was to delete all the old drivers and drivers.json file located at %USERPROFILE%\.wdm
After that everything worked as expected.

It is not a satisfying answer but providing the service is not needed anymore.
I removed the service argument based on Shawn's answer, which resolved the issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

following the answer of @Stephen Genusa, what worked for me is locate the new driver in drivers.json at %USERPROFILE%.wdm and change "/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver" to "chromedriver.exe"

Hellow Guys, Today I had the same problem, but when running my code on another PC it worked normally.
I'll leave the code I use below:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    self.servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=self.servico)
    self.browser.maximize_window()´´´´


Based on this issue raised on the Webdriver Manager for Python GitHub, it looks like something is wrong in the return path logic.
There is a fix in above thread. People who are still using Selenium 3 may need this. Selenium 4.6 or later won't need the Webdriver Manager.
The latest version has fixed this issue:
pip install webdriver-manager==4.0.2

