Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 129.0.6668.60 with binary path
I'm using selenium and ChromeDriver, worked with it several times and have no errors. Suddenly today I got this warning:

The chromedriver version (114.0.5735.90) detected in PATH at C:\Work\Scrape\chromedriver.exe might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (129.0.6668.60); currently, chromedriver 129.0.6668.70 is recommended for chrome 129.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry

and an error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 129.0.6668.60 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Read a 1-year-old answered question here, I already used the code until now. The previous question are between Chromedriver 114 and Chrome 116, now my problem is the Chrome version 129. Should I downgrade my Chrome and how to do it? I'm using selenium 4.20

Your chrome browser seems to have upgraded recently to v129. You need to use matching chromedriver in your selenium code.
Option 1:
Download latest ChromeDriver(v129) from the following link:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable
And use this chromedriver.exe in your driver path. (C:\Work\Scrape\chromedriver.exe)
Options 2: Allow Selenium Manager to download the latest driver for you matching the chrome browser in your system. Code can be as simple as:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()

Refer below answer to know more about Selenium Manager:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774


Thank you, the chromedriver web are a but confusing at first, you'll only see the 114 as the latest. after finding the 129 version it's all good

I ran into this exact same issue. I wonder why its only up to 114 on the chromedriver web download page https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromedriver/downloads
