Not able to launch URL in selenium
I have downloaded the latest version of chromedriver and updated the chrome with the same version.
Also added the selenium jar files.
Getting error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver-win64 (1)\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64.exe
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.\<init\>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at Selenium.OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:16)

Please refer the image
I have added the correct path, also added the .exe but getting the same error. Expecting to launch the flipkart URL.
Here is my code :
package Selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OpenBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver-win64 (1)\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64.exe");                
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
    }
}


Instead of setting the chromedriver.exe manually, why don't you let SeleniumManager do the driver management for you.
Just remove the System.setProperty line and code can be as simple as:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
}

To know more about SeleniumManager, refer below links:

Introducing Selenium Manager
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78342557/7598774
Selenium Manager

