Python: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Failed to create Chrome process
I am trying to set up Selenium for the first time. While executing the following code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name="detach", value=True)

service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url="https://www.google.com")

I am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 329, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 384, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 232, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E53433+25059]
    (No symbol) [0x00DDCE34]
    (No symbol) [0x00CBBEC3]
    (No symbol) [0x00CE9570]
    (No symbol) [0x00CE7169]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2B4D6]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2AC9A]
    (No symbol) [0x00D21C96]
    (No symbol) [0x00CF3FAC]
    (No symbol) [0x00CF4F3D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01145593+3113795]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0115A25A+3198986]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01152A32+3168226]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF32A0+680016]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE577D]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE2A28]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE2BC5]
    (No symbol) [0x00DD5820]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7510FCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770B809E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770B806E+238]

I tried specifying the Chrome binary path using the following code (the chromedriver.exe is in the same location):
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name="detach", value=True)

service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url="https://www.google.com")

... only to get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 329, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 384, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python\Day48a\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 232, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Failed to create Chrome process.
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E53433+25059]
    (No symbol) [0x00DDCE34]
    (No symbol) [0x00CBBEC3]
    (No symbol) [0x00CEA97B]
    (No symbol) [0x00CE7169]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2B4D6]
    (No symbol) [0x00D2AC9A]
    (No symbol) [0x00D21C96]
    (No symbol) [0x00CF3FAC]
    (No symbol) [0x00CF4F3D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01145593+3113795]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0115A25A+3198986]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01152A32+3168226]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF32A0+680016]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE577D]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE2A28]
    (No symbol) [0x00DE2BC5]
    (No symbol) [0x00DD5820]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7510FCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770B809E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770B806E+238]

My Chrome version: 131.0.6778.85
How can I resolve this?

Your original code works fine for me (although your second attempt gives me an error too), please include enough code to reproduce your problem.

Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Hello lads, thanks for your responses. I have stumbled upon the answer provided by Shawn, however this did not solve the problem. After simplifying the code as therein, I get the following error:
ValueError: The browser path is not a valid file:
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

So as a last resport, I fully uninstalled Chrome from my PC and reinstalled it again and it seems to be working now. Might have been an issue with path to the Chrome browser, however weirdly enough, hardcoding the path did not resolve it...
